# iOS Swift playing audio (aac) from network stream

Tags: ios, swift, audiotoolbox

I'm developing an iOS application and I'm quite new to iOS development. So far I have implemented a h264 decoder from network stream using VideoToolbox, which was quite hard.
Now I need to play an audio stream that comes from network, but with no file involved, just a raw AAC stream read directly from the socket. This streams comes from the output of a ffmpeg instance.
The problem is that I don't know how to start with this, it seems there is little information about this topic. I have already tried with `AVAudioPlayer` but found just silence. I think I have first need to decompress the packets from the stream, just like with the h264 decoder.

I have been trying also with `AVAudioEngine` and `AVAudioPlayerNode` but no sucess, same as with `AVAudioPlayer`. Can someone provide me some guidance? Maybe `AudioToolbox`? `AudioQueue`?

Thank you very much for the help :)

Edit:
I'm playing around with `AVAudioCompressedBuffer` and having no error using `AVAudioEngine` and `AVAudioNode`. But, I don't know what this output means:

`inBuffer: <AVAudioCompressedBuffer@0x6040004039f0: 0/1024 bytes>`

Does this mean that the buffer is empty? I have been trying to feed this buffer in several ways, but always returns something like 0/1024. I think I'm not doing this right:

`compressedBuffer.mutableAudioBufferList.pointee = audioBufferList`

Any idea?

Thank you!

Edit 2:
I'm editing for reflecting my code for decompressing the buffer. Maybe some one can point me in the right direction.
Note: The packet that is ingested by this function actually is passed without the ADTS header (9 bytes) but I have also tried passing it with the header.

```
func decodeCompressedPacket(packet: Data) -> AVAudioPCMBuffer {

    var packetCopy = packet
    var streamDescription: AudioStreamBasicDescription = AudioStreamBasicDescription.init(mSampleRate: 44100, mFormatID: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC, mFormatFlags: UInt32(MPEG4ObjectID.AAC_LC.rawValue), mBytesPerPacket: 0, mFramesPerPacket: 1024, mBytesPerFrame: 0, mChannelsPerFrame: 1, mBitsPerChannel: 0, mReserved: 0)
    let audioFormat = AVAudioFormat.init(streamDescription: &streamDescription)
    let compressedBuffer = AVAudioCompressedBuffer.init(format: audioFormat!, packetCapacity: 1, maximumPacketSize: 1024)

    print("packetCopy count: \(packetCopy.count)")
    var audioBuffer: AudioBuffer = AudioBuffer.init(mNumberChannels: 1, mDataByteSize: UInt32(packetCopy.count), mData: &packetCopy)
    var audioBufferList: AudioBufferList = AudioBufferList.init(mNumberBuffers: 1, mBuffers: audioBuffer)
    var mNumberBuffers = 1
    var packetSize = packetCopy.count
    // memcpy(&compressedBuffer.mutableAudioBufferList[0].mBuffers, &audioBuffer, MemoryLayout<AudioBuffer>.size)
    // memcpy(&compressedBuffer.mutableAudioBufferList[0].mBuffers.mDataByteSize, &packetSize, MemoryLayout<Int>.size)
    // memcpy(&compressedBuffer.mutableAudioBufferList[0].mNumberBuffers, &mNumberBuffers, MemoryLayout<UInt32>.size)

    // compressedBuffer.mutableAudioBufferList.pointee = audioBufferList

    var bufferPointer = compressedBuffer.data

    for byte in packetCopy {
        memset(compressedBuffer.mutableAudioBufferList[0].mBuffers.mData, Int32(byte), MemoryLayout<UInt8>.size)
    }

    print("mBuffers: \(compressedBuffer.audioBufferList[0].mBuffers.mNumberChannels)")
    print("mBuffers: \(compressedBuffer.audioBufferList[0].mBuffers.mDataByteSize)")
    print("mBuffers: \(compressedBuffer.audioBufferList[0].mBuffers.mData)")


    var uncompressedBuffer = uncompress(inBuffer: compressedBuffer)
    print("uncompressedBuffer: \(uncompressedBuffer)")
    return uncompressedBuffer
}
```

Comment: I am also getting the same. Have you got any clue?

Answer (score 6):

So you are right in thinking you will (most likely) need to decompress the packets received from the stream. The idea is to get them to raw PCM format so that this can be sent directly to the audio output. This way you could also apply any DSP / audio manipulation you could want to the audio stream.

---

As you mentioned, you will probably need to be looking into the `AudioQueue` direction and the Apple Docs provide a good example of [streaming audio in realtime](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioQueueProgrammingGuide/AQPlayback/PlayingAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005343-CH3-SW1), although this is in obj-c (in this case I think it may be a good idea to carry this out in obj-c). This is probably the best place to get started (interfacing the obj-c to swift is [super simple](https://www.ios-blog.com/tutorials/objective-c/how-to-use-objective-c-classes-in-swift/)).

---

Looking again at it in Swift there is the class [AVAudioCompressedBuffer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiocompressedbuffer) which seems to handle AAC for your case (would not need to decode the AAC if you get this to work), however there is no direct method for setting the buffer as it is intended for just being a storage container, I believe. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26670756/how-to-play-sound-with-avaudiopcmbuffer) a working example of someone using the [AVAudioCompressedBuffer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiocompressedbuffer) along with an AVAudioFile (maybe you could buffer everything into files in background threads? I think it would be too much IO overhead).

However, if you tackle this in obj-c there is a [post](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/24124) on how to set the AVAudioPCMBuffer (maybe works with AVAudioCompressedBuffer?) directly through `memset` (kind of digusting but at the same time lovely as an embedded programmer myself).

```
// make a silent stereo buffer  
AVAudioChannelLayout *chLayout = [[AVAudioChannelLayout alloc] initWithLayoutTag:kAudioChannelLayoutTag_Stereo];  
AVAudioFormat *chFormat = [[AVAudioFormat alloc] initWithCommonFormat:AVAudioPCMFormatFloat32  
                                                          sampleRate:44100.0  
                                                          interleaved:NO  
                                                        channelLayout:chLayout];  

AVAudioPCMBuffer *thePCMBuffer = [[AVAudioPCMBuffer alloc] initWithPCMFormat:chFormat frameCapacity:1024];  

thePCMBuffer.frameLength = thePCMBuffer.frameCapacity;  

for (AVAudioChannelCount ch = 0; ch < chFormat.channelCount; ++ch) {  
    memset(thePCMBuffer.floatChannelData[ch], 0, thePCMBuffer.frameLength * chFormat.streamDescription->mBytesPerFrame);  
}
```

---

I know this is a lot to take and no way seems like a simple solution, but I think the obj-c `AudioQueue` technique would be my first stop!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much @WoodyDev. Indeed I have been trying all kind of possibilities. For example, using AVAudioConverter did not work for me, as I was getting all kind of errors with `AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer` that I did not manage to solve. Also, I have been playing around with `AVAudioCompressedBuffer`. The problem with this is that it seems I cannot load the data into the `AVAudioCompressedBuffer`, I'm editing my original question to reflect this. But there is no error in the output. This thing is driving me crazy. I thought decoding h264 with VideoToolbox was hard, but this...

Comment: Did you try using *memset* with the pointer returned from [AVAudioCompressedBuffer getData]? [(link here).](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiocompressedbuffer?language=objc) It looks like it will work the same way as the example I posted in my answer (for AVAudioPCMBuffer). I haven't tested it but if logic serves me right then it should all piece together :-)

Comment: What I have tried is using `memcpy` as your example fills a buffer with 0 (silence), for copying the entire `AudioBuffer`. I have also tried making a loop as in your example copying byte per byte, but the output is always the same. Something like `<AVAudioCompressedBuffer@0x6040000152f0: 0/1024 bytes>`. I have tried searching for what that 0/1024 bytes means but it seems there is no documentation on the Internet. I'm gonna update my original post for posting this entire code. Thank you @WoodyDev